# Max command MATLAB

Tags: matlab

My friends and I have been trying to resolve a localized problem in MATLAB code -

It deals with the "max" command - we are trying to find the maximum of R01 and R02, and plot this max against varying values of gamma1. The problem is in the for loop.\

The error message is:

```
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.
Error in SolverDEqnsBoth (line 68)
R0(i) = max(transpose(R01),R02);
```

Here is the code:

```
B       = 2000;
mu      = 0.02;
deltaT  = 0.24;
deltaA  = 1.00;
alpha1  = 0.10;
alpha2  = 0.50;
beta1   = 2.00;
beta2   = 0.47;
gamma1  = 2.00;
gamma2  = 1.50;
v1      = 0.009;
v2      = 0.19;
c1      = 100;
c3      = 2.00;
c4      = 0.50;
N       = 35000;

%%%== Initial conditions ==
S0 = 10000;
H0 = 3000;
E10 = 3500;
E20 = 2000;
I10 = 4000;
I20 = 2500;
T10 = 3000;
T20 = 2000;
A10 = 1800;
A20 = 1700;
A30 = 800;
A40 = 700;

y0 = [S0 H0 E10 E20 I10 I20 T10 T20 A10 A20 A30 A40];

tf = 100;

[t y] = ode15s(@DEqnsBoth,[0:0.1:100],y0);

S = y(:,1);
H = y(:,2);
E1 = y(:,3);
E2 = y(:,4);
I1 = y(:,5);
I2 = y(:,6);
T1 = y(:,7);
T2 = y(:,8);
A1 = y(:,9);
A2 = y(:,10);
A3 = y(:,11);
A4 = y(:,12);


N = S + H + E1 + E2 + I1 + I2 + T1 + T2 + A1 + A2 + A3 + A4;

R01 =(beta1*c1*v1*B)/ ((mu + deltaT + gamma2)*(mu + v1 + gamma1))*mu*N;
R02 = (beta2*c3*B)/((mu+alpha1)*mu*N);

for i = 1:length(gamma1)
gamma1 = [0:0.005:5];
R0 = zeros(1, length(gamma1));
R0(i) = max(transpose(R01),R02);
end 
plot(gamma1,R0)

%plot(t,100.*( S)./N, 'r')
%hold on
%axis square
 %xlabel('days')
 %ylabel('Prevalence (% infected)')
 %axis([0 100 0 100])
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: For one thing, why do you redefine gamma1 inside the loop? Also, could pinpoint the line that gives you the error?

Comment: I'm not sure. Line: R0(i) = max(transpose(R01),R02);

Comment: I changed the code to this: for i = 1:length(gamma1)
R0 = zeros(1, 1001*length(gamma1));
R0(i) = max(transpose(R01),R02);
end 
plot(gamma1,R0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting in:

```
 R0(i) = max([transpose(R01),R02]);
```

I'm getting an error, but it shouldn't be important though.

```
Undefined function 'DEqnsBoth' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

Can you please write down what you get when you do the folowing:

```
size(R01)
size(R02)
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work, except my R02 is something wrong. It's all zeros, except for the initial condition. So the graph is flatlining

Comment: R02 isn't even an array. It is just one value. You have probably missed something.

Comment: OK. I have: >> size(R01)

ans =

        1001           1

>> size(R02)

ans =

           1        1001

>>

Comment: Ok,

`gamma1 = [0:0.005:5];
R0 = zeros(1, length(gamma1));
for i = 1:length(gamma1)
R0(i) = max([transpose(R01),R02]);
end `
I can't suggest something better as I don't know what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Actually `R0(i) = max([transpose(R01),R02]);` will always give the same result because you always use the same `R01` and `R02`. You should change something about it.